# Swift4 constant from URL into UITextlabel

Tags: swift

Sorry for the formatting (cant get it right)

I am new to Swift4. I have managed to get some JSON data from an url. Although i am able to print this information, i have not been able to output this information on my storyboard.

I have a button and when i click it the data gets retrieved and printed into the console. I want to put this data into a label.

I thought it would be as simple as
self.Label2.text = title
But no content is added to the Label2. (in fact the label dissapears when clicking the button)

When i put text in the label, the content does get changed. Just not when i try to output my constant into the storyboard.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? Or point me into the right direction. Thanks in advance!

I have tried setting the value of Label2 directly into the getJsonFromUrl function.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var Label2: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func getJsonFromUrl(){
    navigationItem.title = "REST API"

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://gipaa.nl/com_json.php") else {return}
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                return }
        do{
            //here dataResponse received from a network request
            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                dataResponse, options: [])


            guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String: Any]] else{
                return
            }


            guard let title = jsonArray[0]["name"] as? String else{ return }
           print(title)



        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    }


    @IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

        getJsonFromUrl()

        self.Label2.text = title
        self.Label1.text = "hmm"

    }

}
```

Value of title into Label2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two major issues:

1. `guard let title = ...` creates a **local** variable which goes out of scope. In the `Button` function you are assigning the `title` property of the `UIViewController` which is something completely different.
2. The data task in `getJsonFromUrl` works asynchronously, you have to add a completion handler

   ```
   func getJsonFromUrl(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {

       ...

       guard let title = jsonArray[0]["name"] as? String else { return }
       completion(title)
   ```

   ---

   ```
   @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) { // function names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter
       getJsonFromUrl { title in 
          self.Label2.text = title
       }
   ...
   ```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Did had to add 

getJsonFromUrl { title in
            
   DispatchQueue.main.async {self.label2.text = title}                  }

To get it to work but now i get it on my storyboard :)